# set a property value from object in task

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have an object called Settings.
it has a property called BusyDoingAction of type bool

```
public class Settings : ObservableObject
    {
        private bool busyDoingAction;
        public bool BusyDoingAction 
        {
            get { return this.busyDoingAction; }
            set
            {
                this.busyDoingAction= value;
                OnPropertyChanged(() => BusyDoingAction);
            }
        }
```

I have another class called FileAdding,

```
private readonly string[] files;
private bool busy;
public FileAdding(string[] files, bool busyAction)
        {
            this.files = files;
            this.busy= busyAction;
        }
```

now, in my ViewModel I have the following:

```
var fileAdding = new FileAdding(files, Settings.BusyDoingAction);            

            if (!fileAdding.Initialize())
                return;

            Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                fileAdding.Execute(CToken);
                return fileAdding.Deinitialize();
            }, CToken);
        }
```

and in the FileAdding Initialize() function I have:

```
public bool Initialize()
        {
           busy  = true;
           return true;
        }

public bool Deinitialize()
         {
           busy  = false;
           return true;
         }
```

the problem is:
the BusyDoingAction is not changing in the FileAdding and iam not getting any value changed notification for that property ..

The Property is bound to the mainGrid in my application, and iam using it to detect whether the application is busy and enable/disable the grid depending on the value of BusyDoingAction

I don't know what iam doing wrong, but I need to set the property value of BusyDoingAction in that busyDoingAction.Intialize/Deinitialize function ..

any help is really appreciated ..

Comment: you are not setting the BusyDoingAction anywhere in FileAdding.. you just updated the variable busy...

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake ...I corrected the code again ... how to get to update the BusyDoingAction then !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `FileAdding` class should like this.. you should have `Settings` property in it...and bind to `Settings.BusyDoingAction` from it on UI.

```
    private readonly string[] files;
    private Settings setting;
    public FileAdding(string[] files, Settings setting)
            {
                this.files = files;
                this.setting= setting;
            }

public Settings Settings
        {
            get { return this.setting; }
            set
            {
                this.setting= value;
                OnPropertyChanged(() => Settings);
            }
        }

public bool Initialize()
        {
           Settings.BusyDoingAction = true;
           return true;
        }

public bool Deinitialize()
         {
           Settings.BusyDoingAction = false;
           return true;
         }
```

Comment: THANK U..i forgot that iam working with the FileAdding Property only not the Settings property..thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Doing:

`var fileAdding = new FileAdding(files, Settings.BusyDoingAction);`

you are simply copying the current value or `Settings.BusyDoingAction` to `FileAction.busy`.

There is no link between `Settings.BusyDoingAction` and `FileAdding.busy`

To solve your problem, one way is to pass the `Settings` reference to `FileAdding`:

```
private readonly string[] files;
private readonly Settings settings;
public FileAdding(string[] files, Settings settings)
{
    this.files = files;
    this.settings = settings;
}
```

and then in:

```
public bool Initialize()
{
   this.settings.BusyDoingAction = true;
   return true;
}

public bool Deinitialize()
{
   this.settings.BusyDoingAction = false;
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ..I didn't notice that iam just working with the FileAdding property ..thanks again